# How can I enable multiple entries for an existing Custom Data Set

Tags: custom-fields, multi-record

I have an existing Custom Data Set that I want to enable multiple entries for, but when I open the settings and try to enable it, I'm unable to- when I click on the option, nothing happens.

Comment: I was able to create a new CDS, enable multiple records, and move all the fields to the new CDS.

Comment: right. i do not think there is any way to convert apart from approach you took. perhaps if that has worked you can add as your own Answer here